# Simple login script with sha256 hashing

Tags: javascript, php, pdo

I have been using this code for a while. I got it from a tutorial 5 years back. Now I'm wondering if it still is secure, or if it's time to find a new one? Maybe it has never been secure enough.

**LOGIN**

```
<?php 
//Connect to database
require("include/config.php");

//Empty Variable
$submitted_username = '';

//Check if something is posted
if(!empty($_POST)){ 

    //Check if user exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE usr_email = :usr_email";
    $query_params = array(':usr_email' => $_POST['usr_email']); 
    try{ 
        $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params); 
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to run query: " . $ex->getMessage()); } 

    //Fetch result
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    //Reset var
    $login_ok = false;

    //If usr exists, check password
    if($row){
        //Check if password matches
        $check_password = hash('sha256', $_POST['usr_password'] . $row['usr_salt']); 
        for($round = 0; $round < 65536; $round++){
            $check_password = hash('sha256', $check_password . $row['usr_salt']);
        }
        if($check_password === $row['usr_password']){
            $login_ok = true;
        } 
    }

//LOGIN OK
    if($login_ok){ 
        //UNSET VARS
        unset($row['usr_salt']); 
        unset($row['usr_password']);

        //LOG USR LOGIN DATA
        $dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        //Create array
        $usr_data = array(
            ':usr_id' => $row['id'],
            ':usr_name' => $row['usr_fname']. " " . $row['usr_lname'],
            ':dateTime' => $dateTime,
            ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
        );


        //CREATE SESSION 
        $_SESSION['usr'] = $row;

        //REDIRECT TO STARTPAGE
        header("Location: start.php");

    } 
    else{ 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Fel uppgifter..');</script>"; 
        $submitted_username = htmlentities($_POST['usr_email'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'); 
    } 
} 
?>
```

**CONFIG**

```
$options = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'); 
try { $db = new PDO("mysql:host={$host};dbname={$dbname};charset=utf8", $username, $password, $options); } 
catch(PDOException $ex){ die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage());} 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

//SET HEADER
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); 

//START SESSION
if(!isset($_SESSION)){ 
    session_start([
        'cookie_lifetime' => 86400,
    ]);
}

//SET TIMEZONE
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Stockholm'); 
?>
```

**CHECK IF LOGGED IN**

```
<?php

//CHECK IF USR IS LOGGED IN
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo "<script>window.location = '/index.php'</script>";
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining why you call the `hash` function 65537 times?

Comment: @slepic The specific number has likely come from \$2^{16} = 65536\$. The purpose is to make the password hashing slower and therefore harder to brute force it. See Roland Illig's answer for an explanation why that might be a good, but not the best possible idea.

Comment: @AlexV Hmm i see... But wouldnt it be better to limit the rate of requests on the "post login" endpoint to léts say 1 request per second per IP? Regular users probably never do two login attempts within a second And So they dont need to notice the slowdown. While the 1 in million visitors that Is a hacker still can't Brute Force it...

Comment: Anyway if I post a very long random password. The hash function May Crash your webserver. It Is wise to limit the length of the password before passing it to a hashing algorithm...

Comment: @AlexV What do you mean? Sure, if the attacker attacks db, then no rate limit on webserver side will have influence. But the same is true for doing 65k hashes in the php process.... What's your point?

Comment: @slepic This is not something one should discuss in the comments. Maybe have a look at [this site](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm), the [specification of PBKDF2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2898#section-4.2), or [this extensive answer on Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31846) to learn more.

Comment: @AlexV The RFC you linked says: "Obsoleted by: 8018". Maybe you should update your library of citations. :)

Comment: @RolandIllig Thanks for the hint. I have skipped the header and went straight to the index looking for "Iteration Count" ;-)

Comment: @AlexV I dont think we understand each other. Definitely I dont understand you. The links make no sense to me as a response to my comment.... Maybe if there Is some Tiny related bit, but im not gonna read entire spec for that, sry...

Comment: @slepic, to help you understand, the reason why those links from AlexV helps is, they cover PBKDF2 and other key-stretching algorithms, which are the current standard in password storage. Re-hashing the password 65536 times is a "poor man's PBKDF2" (this is a decent implementation: it puts the salt in the right place). The goal _isn't_ to slow down how long it takes to log in, though that is a side effect. **The goal is, if someone gets the key-stretched passwords, it will take them significantly longer to do an offline attack** and there is no possibility of a rainbow table.

Comment: @Ghedipunk problém here Is that AlexV deleted the only comment I was actually referring to (guess why). The rest makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a timing attack. To see whether a user has registered or not, I can try to login. If it fails fast, the user is not registered. If it takes time, the user is registered. To fix this information disclosure, calculate some dummy hash even if the user cannot be found in the database.

The SQL part is fine.

The `$submitted_username` calls `htmlentities` too early. The only correct time to call `htmlentities` is exactly at the point where you embed a text into an HTML snippet. That doesn't happen in your code, though. To fix this, rename the variable from `submitted_username` to `submitted_username_html`, to prevent it from being used in any other context. For example, code that reads `db_insert($submitted_username_html)` looks wrong enough to warrant a thorough code review.

Your code could benefit from being split into a few well-named functions. After doing that, the main code might read like this:

```php
$logged_in_user = log_in($_POST);
if ($logged_in_user === FALSE) {
    // …
} else {
    // …
}
```

When you extract all the detailed code into a function, you can use early returns for all the error cases. And when you step through the code using a debugger, you can easily skip over all the details of the login process, if you are not interested in it.

In the config part, you should prefix all variable names with `db_`, to avoid confusing the `username` with the `submitted_username`. Or group them into an object called `db_config`. Then you can access it as `$db_config['username']`. There, the identifier `username` is appropriate since it is qualified by the word `db_config`, which makes it unambiguous.

The SHA-256 algorithm you use for hashing is [not secure enough anymore](https://dusted.codes/sha-256-is-not-a-secure-password-hashing-algorithm) since specialized hardware can compute it too fast, even with 65536 iterations. PHP has a built-in [set of password hashing algorithms](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php). Just use that instead of iterating on your own. Migrating from your custom password hashing to the PHP default will cost a bit of time and work, but it's worth the effort. And since you are not the first to do that, there's already plenty of documentation on it. Probably. Hopefully.

Comment: Just wonder if the timing attack is significant enough to be detectable over network delays?  I can see how it can be mitigated, but just like to understand the underlying need for these things.

Comment: Yes, it is. Assuming that a single hashing operation takes a microsecond, 65536 of them takes 65 milliseconds. And even if it we're just a tenth of that time, that's still easily detectable. Maybe you have to perform several measurements to get confident, but still yes.

Answer (score 3):

I can see two issues related to security (but both do not pose an immediate threat being rather a potential issue):

- the insufficient hashing algorithm. Nowadays computers are FAST. Means they could calculate billions *ordinary* hashes per second. And, in case your database gets compromised, it would be rather easy to get raw passwords from it. A secure password hash must be *slow*. And PHP has one, implemented in the password_hash function. So instead of your own hash you must use a built-in function
- I bet you never paid much attention to the error reporting part of your code, as your application seldom throws an error. Yet, when it happens, it's a complete disaster. An error message could contain a lot of sensitive information about your system. Not likely that it could be used directly to hack into your site, but it can help a hacker a lot. Besides, it just makes no sense to send an error message right away - a site user wouldn't make any sense of it. You chould forget about die() in your scripts. The best thing you can do is to leave the error message alone.

The only other note I can make, there is a lot of rather useless conditions or the unused code. I rewrote your code based on the review above:

```
<?php 
//Connect to database
require("include/config.php");

//Check if something is posted
if($_POST){ 

    //Check if user exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE usr_email = :usr_email";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute([':usr_email' => $_POST['usr_email']]); 
    //Fetch result
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    //If usr exists, check password
    if($row && password_verify($_POST['usr_password'], $row['usr_password'])
    {
        unset($row['usr_password']);

        //CREATE SESSION 
        $_SESSION['usr'] = $row;

        //REDIRECT TO STARTPAGE
        header("Location: start.php");
        exit();
    } else { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Fel uppgifter..');</script>"; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: The $_POST variable should be checked for presence of those keys before accessing them. Simple checking if post is empty or not is not enough (well, to be formally complete... Its probably enough for the script to work...).

Comment: @slepic that are you going to do in keys are undefined?

Comment: Redirect to hp maybe or back to login page. Idk. Its not my project...

Comment: OH And not just presence of keys. But also correct data types of the values under those keys (strings in OP's case).

Comment: @slepic everything sent via HTTP POST is a string. And in case the key is not set, there will be a PHP error. Given your app do care for PHP errors, there will be a "redirect" to the error page. Looks enough to me?

Comment: Nope. Everything sent via HTTP POST is a string or (nested) array of strings. And does it really look like this guy (OP) cares about a common error handler? I don't think so. Anyway I talk about general best practice, not the specific case in question. I remember one interview question where code was provided and find a security hole was the question. Everything looked fine as long as one assumed the post variable cannot be anything else than a string. The moment they sent array, the code logged in user with incorrect password or something like that... better safe than sorry...

Comment: And btw anytime your code reaches a common error handler. It doesnt mean it is ok. It means the code needs some fixing... The common error handler is just the last piece of chain, The ultimate place responsible for letting you know something went wrong. It is not the correct end of your program.

Comment: Ok, it needs to be fixed. What kind of fix? Either propose a fix or don't push someone down the road you don't know yourself

Comment: I already proposed the fix. Check for the keys presence and the values being strings. Otherwise redirect or maybe do nothing like it is done when $_POST is empty. You dont check your array keys if you want. I just hope OP is reading this and that he can make sense to the desire that only string variables are passed to functions accepting strings (like password_verify does).

Comment: "redirect or do nothing" is anything but a fix. All right I can think of a reasonable action - a 400 HTTP status. But that's good only for a live site. A typo in the field name would make you bang your head on the wall trying to get why nothing works. So on a dev server you'd want the actual error message, in order to fix the error - that's what error messages are actually for. So to have such a distinction I'll have to throw an exception of a certain kind. Now I'd have to introduce exceptions, custom exceptions and an extended custom error handler, totaling in much more code than the OP has.

Comment: Hmm and so because of dev environment, you let it make errors on production? Learn to use debugger instead of banging your head against the wall. And you don't have to introduce any exceptions anyway. Can't you just accept that `if (!empty($_POST))` is just a lazy way of saying `if (isset($_POST['usr_password'], $_POST['usr_email']) && \is_string($_POST['usr_password']) && \is_string($_POST['usr_email']))`. Meaning "Is there all the expected post data?"instead of "Is there any post data?". Whatever is done in either branch is irrelevant.

Comment: It *is* relevant. Internet is full of such rants, "you must do something but I don't care what exactly". Unlike those I prefer my advise to be reasonable, plausible and complete. Now let's agree to disagree. While you prefer an open-ended suggestion which the OP is bound to implement by themselves, I prefer a complete solution that works. And no, debugger is useless if you wrote a code to intentionally silence the errors messages.

Comment: I haven't silenced any errors. I have prevented them. By all means inform the client that `usr_password` and/or `usr_email` fields are required (and to be strings), whichever is missing (or has wrong value). Your solution is not reasonable, it is ignorant. It is not complete, it is erroneous. You made no difference between your backend code errors and client errors. You let the client error convert to php code errors, instead of detecting client errors and handling them reasonably and never letting any client error cause an error on the php language level.

Comment: You silenced apossible undefined variable error with isset. It's a very common mistake, 99% php users are doing that. It's a mistake nevertheless. We already agreed that your "reasonable" "what you put inside if() doesn't matter" is no more reasonable than mine "do not add an if() if you don't know what to put inside". never letting any client error cause an error on the php language level is a thing but I cannot think of any solution that fits for this simple example.

Comment: I added my own answer to show you that it can be easily communicated to the client. Anyway I don't see your problem with isset. It doesnt hide undefined variable. It is the place where you check for it and then do something or something else. Thats called the handling of the situation, not ignoring it.

Comment: Thanks, I already upvoted it

Answer (score 1):

I object that all the required post fields should be checked for presence and expected type and report the missing fields to the client as opposed to letting it convert to php errors.

As a simple solution we might report to client using js alert as it is done in another case already.

```
<?php 
//Connect to database
require("include/config.php");

//Check if something is posted
if(isset($_POST['usr_password'], $_POST['usr_email'])
   && \is_string($_POST['usr_password'])
   && \is_string($_POST['usr_email'])
   && \strlen($_POST['usr_password']) < 1000){ 

    //Check if user exists
    $query = "SELECT * FROM usrs WHERE usr_email = :usr_email";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query); 
    $stmt->execute([':usr_email' => $_POST['usr_email']]); 
    //Fetch result
    $row = $stmt->fetch(); 

    //If usr exists, check password
    if($row && password_verify($_POST['usr_password'], $row['usr_password'])
    {
        unset($row['usr_password']);

        //CREATE SESSION 
        $_SESSION['usr'] = $row;

        //REDIRECT TO STARTPAGE
        header("Location: start.php");
        exit();
    } else { 
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Fel uppgifter..');</script>"; 
    } 
} else if (!empty($_POST)) {
  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('usr_email and usr_password are required and password must be less than 1000 chars');</script>"; 
}
```

It could be a different message for each case, but for illustration I believe this should be enough.

Further I have added check for password length to prevent hashing very long strings.

Comment: If you're going to check the plaintext password length, you might as well follow a standard while doing it ([NIST 800-63B sec 5.1.1.2](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/sp800-63b.html#sec5) says  the minimum maximum should be 64 characters), or at least set the limit to match the constraints of your key stretching algorithm -- With `password_hash()` set at current defaults, this is 72 characters. Despite your claims in comments to the question, even a naive implementation of PBKDF2 is not going to DOS a site when given an overly large plaintext; only the first round will be affected...

Comment: ... The web server's other resources are going to pass failsafe thresholds (maximum upload size, maximum memory size, etc.) long before a key stretching algorithm can be used to make a CPU unresponsive for extended periods... and if you are attacking a key stretching algorithm using a DDOS attack, the site _should_ (see the NIST standards, linked above) have other rate limiting factors that will keep the authentication system from being leveraged to magnify a DDOS.

Comment: (Relevant section in NIST 800-63B for rate limiting is section 5.2.2, by the way.)

Comment: Shouldn’t variable cleansing be done somewhere other than program flow?  I see the reason for this if scripting procedurally; but oh my I would hate to have to sift through these `if()` statements because they are in effect validating input in addition to directing program flow. You can’t look at that four line if() and immediately grasp everything it’s doing; and if you have to make a change to the variables being submitted, your program flow is invalidated. (I don’t have a better solution to propose; still struggling with it myself)

Comment: @TimMorton in real world you probably dont put all the conditions into one if. You have a separáte one for each of them And some specific message May be passed to client in each case. This all May be moved to a validátor class. I just tried to keep it simple And Focus on my main thought, that you should make sure that only expected things make it to places of your code where they wont crash your program or invoke any other unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Is this a good script?: https://phppot.com/php/secure-remember-me-for-login-using-php-session-and-cookies/

Answer (score 0):

#### Unused variable, single-use variable

In this section:

> ```
> //LOG USR LOGIN DATA
> ```

```
$dateTime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
//Create array
$usr_data = array(
    ':usr_id' => $row['id'],
    ':usr_name' => $row['usr_fname']. " " . $row['usr_lname'],
    ':dateTime' => $dateTime,
    ':ip' => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']
);
```

The variable `$dateTime` is only used once, so there is not much need to store the value in a variable. The value can be used when creating `$usr_data` without storing it in the variable. Also, `$usr_data` doesn't appear to be used in this code.

#### Redirect with `header()` instead of Javascript

The last block of code uses a JavaScript redirect:

> ```
> //CHECK IF USR IS LOGGED IN
> ```

```
if(empty($_SESSION['user'])){
    echo "<script>window.location = '/index.php'</script>";
    die("Redirecting to index.php"); 
}
```

It would be simpler just to redirect using [`header('Location: /index.php')`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) as the other code does, unless the user was supposed to see the redirecting message for a set amount of time (e.g. 2 seconds), however it is possible the user might have JavaScript disabled and thus the redirect would not happen.